# How to show xml on browser with output_buffering disabled

Tags: php, xml, ob-start

I'm trying to show a xml file in my browser, but I keep getting a *headers already sent by* warning by php. I'm using ob_start() and ob_flush() it helped in other situations, but in this case I still get this warning.

```
    ob_start();
    header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1');
    //..
    //getting data
    //..
    if($result)
    {
        $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'ISO-8859-1');
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
        //...
        //generate xml structure
        //..
    }
    echo $doc->saveXML();
    ob_flush();
```

Comment: obviously the headers are being sent before you call `ob_start`. If there is no other code before it, then often it is because there's a space or a newline character before the starting `<?php` tag which is being output, and which sends the headers automatically. You might want to check for that.

Comment: Eliminate white space before header is being invoked and then try executing script

Comment: There was no white space. I encode my script as UTF-8 without BOM and it worked. thanks btw!